# How to implement the function to swipe to next page in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm now working on implementing the function to swipe to the next page for people to browse. Yeah, it's just like the swipe function of Tinder. I have searched the Internet but only found swipe to delete. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Your question seems a little too broad, it's hard to give a concise answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 14):

What you want is [`PageView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)

It's a widget that includes all the logic for page swipe gestures.

Answer (score 11):

You may use [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html). it has almost all drags available. Here is an example:

```
GestureDetector(
  onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _onHorizontalDrag(details),
  child: Container()
)
```

and the function:

```
void _onHorizontalDrag(DragEndDetails details) {
  if(details.primaryVelocity == 0) return; // user have just tapped on screen (no dragging)

    if (details.primaryVelocity.compareTo(0) == -1)
      print('dragged from left');
    else 
      print('dragged from right');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this..

```
GestureDetector (
  onPanUpdate: (dis) {
    if (dis.delta.dx > 0) {
      //User swiped from left to right
    } else if (dis.delta.dx < 0) {
      //User swiped from right to left
    }
  }
  child: yourWidget,
)
```

Hope it answers your question..

Comment: Just note there is a typo on the onPanUpdate method name :)

Comment: It's corrected now.. thanks for that :)